# Tori in three-space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Recently I was talking to an alien who does not know complex function theory. I was trying to convince her that the set of conformal equivalence classes of smooth embedded tori in $R^3$ is two parametric. Is there a nice two-parametric family of tori in $R^3$ which are pairwise conformally non-equivalent?

I do not have an exact definition of ``nice''. Maximally symmetric, canonical in some sense. Or such that it is intuitively clear that they are all in different conformal classes. The standard model (a circle rotated around a line) gives only
one-parametric family up to conformal equivalence.

EDIT. I understand that all conformal tori EXIST in $R^3$. But is it possible to
show (describe, draw, make a 3-d model) a torus in $R^3$ which is not conformally equivalent to a ``rectangular'' torus ? And this can be proved just by looking at its shape in $R^3$.

Comment: Wouldn't stereographic projections (to $R^3$) of lifts of curves in the base of the Hopf fibration suffice?  Perhaps this isn't sufficiently simple...

Comment: Can you show a picture in $R^3$? I would be satisfied with some small piece of the family.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko See the images in this paper of Pinkall http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/SS12/MathVisII/Pinkall%20-%201985%20-%20Hopf%20tori%20in%20S3.pdf

Comment: In fact, Pinkall seems to completely answer your question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a 1961 result by Adriano Garsia that *every* conformal class can be represented by an embedded surface. His proof seems to be reasonably constructive, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53999/conformal-embedding-of-riemann-surfaces-into-3-space) (and answers thereto).

**EDIT** Pinkall, in [the paper cited by j.c. in his comme](http://www3.math.tu-berlin.de/geometrie/Lehre/SS12/MathVisII/Pinkall%20-%201985%20-%20Hopf%20tori%20in%20S3.pdf)nt, explicitly solves the question for the case of genus 1 (as asked by the OP).

Comment: I believe this. But can one make ONE smooth torus in $R^3$, and convince me somehow that it is not conformally equivalent to a rectangular torus?

Comment: Yes. You can make non-geodesic elastic curves in the 2-sphere which oscillate around a great circle. They have enclosed area which is equal to the area of the hemisphere, but the lenght is strictly greater than the lenght of the great circle. Thus, Pinkall's formula for the conformal type implies, that you obtain a rhombic, non-square torus. The existence of these elastic curves follows from theorem 3 in arxiv.1303.1445.

Comment: link to the paper in Sebastian's comment http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1445