# Embedding Riemann surfaces into $\mathbb P^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, teichmuller-theory

Suppose I am given a Riemann surface $\Sigma_g$ of genus $g$. What is known about the sufficient and necessary conditions needed on $\Sigma_g$ to have an embedding into $\mathbb P^2$?

If $\mathcal T_g$ is the Teichmuller space of genus $g$ Riemann surfaces, is there any way to intrinsically describe the subspace of plane curves?

Comment: If $g > 0$, then an embedding is not surjective (because $\Sigma_g \not\cong \mathbb{P}^1$), so there is a point $p \in \mathbb{P}^1$ not in the image, so $\Sigma_g$ embeds into $\mathbb{P}^1\setminus\{p\} \cong \mathbb{C}$ which is impossible as $\mathbb{C}$ does not have compact submanifolds other than finite sets of points.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I meant $\mathbb P^2$, not $\mathbb P^1$. Sorry about that.

Comment: What kind of data do you have for your mystery surface?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any sufficient conditions known that were a significant departure from an immediate tautology.  Call me sceptical.

Comment: @IgorRivin I don't have a particular surface. I am looking at the space of all plane curves and I want to relate this to something which is a little more familiar to me (like Teichmuller space or moduli space of genus $g$ surfaces). It's a bit of an open ended question. Are there any conditions that prevent a Riemann surface from being embedded into $\mathbb P^2$? I know that hyperelliptic genus 3 surfaces cannot be embedded into $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: By the genus formula for smooth plane curves of degree $d$, unless $g=(d-1)(d-2)/2$ for some integer $d\ge 1$ the answer is negative. I don't know what happens for the "exceptional" values.

Comment: For conformal embeddings, isn't the question answered here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53999/conformal-embedding-of-riemann-surfaces-into-3-space

Answer (score 5):

If I am not mistaken, for the exceptional values of the genus, the locus of degree $d$ plane curves has (complex) dimension
$$
\frac{(d+2)(d+1)}{2}-9
$$
sitting inside a moduli space of dimension
$$
\frac{3(d-1)(d-2)}{2}-3
$$
so it becomes relatively small as $d$ increases.

This [article by Landesman](http://web.stanford.edu/~aaronlan/assets/plane-curve-stack.pdf) seems to be pertinent for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I am completely unfamiliar with stacks, so I guess it's time to study!

Comment: Given a curve of genus $ g = \frac{(d-1)(d-2)}{2} $ asking "is this a plane curve' is very hard afaik.  I'll add two comments in case they are helpful to your situation.  Firstly, that the curve poses a complete $g^2_d$ is obviously necessary, but isn't sufficient.  A simple example would be a curve of genus 5 that is trigonal.  The 'complementary' linear system is a $g^2_5$ .  Secondly, I think that Lazarsfeld (with co-authors ?) has shown that at least 'usually ' a $g^2_d$ on a curve is unique.  hth

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about Teichmuller theory, so I won't attempt an answer to your question.  However, there is a paper by Marc Coppens, " On G. Martens' Characterization of Plane Curves" in which he proves that if X has d+1 mutually independent $g^1_d$'s, then X is isomorphic to a plane curve of degree d+1.  The paper is behind a pay wall, so I haven't been able to read the details.  The paper claims this bound is sharp.  I don't know what this means from a Teichmuller point of view.  From an algebraic geometry view, it seems interesting to me.